# Checkbox Selected Event not Available for UWP Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, checkbox, xamarin.forms, uwp

i am using Messier16.Forms.Checkbox library for Checkbox Control in Xamarin Windows App. it does not have Selected event.

Kindly suggest any library in xamarin UWP project for Checkbox control which contains Selected Event.

Thanks in Advance

Reddy Krishna

Answer (score 1):

From the sample source of `Messier16.Forms.Controls.Checkbox`:

```
checkbox.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Checked"))
    {
        cb2.IsEnabled = checkbox.Checked;
        cb3.Checked = !checkbox.Checked;
    }
};
```

Re: https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls/blob/master/Sample/SampleLocalApp/SampleLocalApp/Pages/CheckboxPages/CheckboxCodePage.cs#L31